# Exporting objectid

Tags: powershell

I have a list of device names exported to an csv file.

I need to import this csv to then query the data and export the objectid of these computers from azure.

I am using the below and the error I am receiving is beneath

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
$test3 = import-csv -path "C:\temp\test3.xml"
Get-MsolDevice -Name $test3.Name | Select-Object -Property ObjectID | Export-CSV -Path "C:\temp\test9.xml"**


Get-MsolDevice : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Name'. Specified method is not supported.

At line:1 char:22
+ Get-MsolDevice -Name $test3.Name | Select-Object -Property ObjectID | ...
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-MsolDevice], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.GetDevice
```

Comment: If your input file is XML, then `Import-Csv` won't do you any good.

Answer (score 1):

`$test3.Name` is going to return a collection of strings if there is more than one row in the CSV. You'll need to iterate over each like so:

```
$objectIds = $test3.Name | Foreach-Object {
  Get-MsolDevice -Name $_ |
    Select-Object -Property ObjectID
}
$objectIds | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\test9.xml" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: They didn't day they need to export to XML, their code runs `Export-Csv`.